# Parameter can't target to the correct file

Tags: scala

I have a TokenCommandResult class

```
sealed class TokenCommandResult {
    class Success(val response: OIDCTokenResponse) : TokenCommandResult()
    class Error(val error: TokenErrorResponse) : TokenCommandResult()
    class Fault(val exception: Throwable) : TokenCommandResult()
}
```

when I used the TokenCommandResult in my main function, I got error

```
object common.auth.oidc.TokenCommandResult.Success is not a value
object common.auth.oidc.TokenCommandResult.Error is not a value
object common.auth.oidc.TokenCommandResult.Fault is not a value
```

```
result match {
            case TokenCommandResult.Success => printError("w", "result.res")
            case TokenCommandResult.Error => printError(format, "result.error.errorObject.description")
            case TokenCommandResult.Fault => printError(format, "result.exception.message")
        }
```

I clicked the go to implementation, it goes to the source code, not the one I defined, how to fix this issue?

```
public sealed class TokenCommandResult private constructor() {
    public final class Error public constructor(error: com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.TokenErrorResponse) : common.auth.oidc.TokenCommandResult {
        public final val error: com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.TokenErrorResponse /* compiled code */
    }

    public final class Fault public constructor(exception: kotlin.Throwable) : common.auth.oidc.TokenCommandResult {
        public final val exception: kotlin.Throwable /* compiled code */
    }

    public final class Success public constructor(response: com.nimbusds.openid.connect.sdk.OIDCTokenResponse) : common.auth.oidc.TokenCommandResult {
        public final val response: com.nimbusds.openid.connect.sdk.OIDCTokenResponse /* compiled code */
    }
}
```

Comment: There is not a single `TokenCommandResult.Success` rather there are infinite `tokenCommandResult.Success` for each value `tokenCommandResult` that is an instance of `TokenCommandResult` - You probably don't want nor need that, and thus you should just move those inside the companion object.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I'm not that understand, can you explain more or show me the code should I do?

Comment: You probably just want to define a simple ADT like this one: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/WiGkvjKwSTWsToutOxMMGA

Comment: `TokenCommandResult.Success` is a type, not a value. To `match` a value of that type you'd use `case x:TokenCommandResult.Success =>`

Comment: @jwvh thank you! Thats the issue!